# Use complex jquery selector with PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, jquery, puppeteer-sharp

I am new to PuppeteerSharp and I have searched already on the internet for several hours and also the documentation, but I don't seem to find a solution to my problem.

Now, I have a table with some rows on my webpage (see attached picture). I need to find the row that has some text in one of the columns, and click the button left to it (the black one with an arrow).

I have got my button (at least the td) with JQuery in Firefox Dev tools like this:

```
$("td: Contains('41818397111')").parent().find("td[id = 'InvoiceDetails']")"
```

But I do not know how to use this information in PuppeteerSharp

I have tried:

```
ElementHandle element = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("td:Contains('41818397111')");
ElementHandle hanlde = await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<ElementHandle>("e=> e.parent().find(\"td[id=['InvoiceDetails']\")", element);


await page.ClickAsync($("td: Contains('41818397111')").parent().find("td[id = 'InvoiceDetails']")")
```

but neither one works. I think I am missing some information.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: jquery selectors are not valid css selectors

Answer (score 0):

So, after many tries and a lot of searched, I ended up switching to Selenium, which seems to have better documentation and a lot of examples here.
This is the code, that worked for me:

```
string locator1 = "td:Contains(\'41818397111\')";
string locator2 = "td[id = \'InvoiceDetails\']";
IWebElement webElement = driver.FindElement(Selenium.WebDriver.Extensions.By.JQuerySelector(locator1).Parent().Find(locator2));
webElement.Click();
```